# SSDT - Track database changes from DACPAC deployment

Tags: tfs-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and TFS 2015 to create an SSDT project and deploy the DACPAC via TFS.

If I test the project in Visual Studio by publishing a profile, I'm able to view all the changes to the destination database (ex. Dropping Tables, etc) in the "Messages" tab.

I'm not seeing that same kind of output when I publish the DACPAC through TFS.  There are timestamps when Deployment has started and finished, but no information on what is actually modified in the database.

Is there anywhere I can view a log of database changes that occurred when a DACPAC was published?

**EDIT**:
I'm using a WinRM - SQL Server DB Deployment task in TFS Release Management to deploy the DACPAC.

Comment: How are you performing the publishing? "Through TFS" could mean any number of things.

Comment: @DanielMann, I added clarification to the question.

Comment: Short of adding in some sort of task to generate the script and/or the change report, I don't think there's an easy way to get this.  I guess if you have all of the dacpacs in sequence, you could schema compare the prior one to the most recent one for a report/diff.  Might also be missing something capturing that output, but I'm not familiar w/ TFS. We captured it in Jenkins without too many issues, but that's a different platform.

Comment: Where is the DacPac file located [Local/target server] ?

Comment: @Shalem, it's copied to the target server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `command line` task to use **SqlPackage.exe** tool to generate a difference report between database. The syntax is:

```
/Action:DeployReport /SourceFile:$dacpac-path /TargetConnectionString:$constr /OutputPath:$reportoutputfilepath
```

Useful links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx
- https://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/06/continuous-deployment-of-databases-part-2-sqlpackage-exe/

Answer (score 2):

There are several artifacts generated when you run deployment:

1. DeploymentReport_X.txt --> This one has the steps performed
2. your_project_name.publish.sql --> This is the actual script executed on source

Comment: Are those only accessible to people who have access to the build server?

Comment: Sure, but you can put them to shared location