# Why would a dacpac fail to update a view on an azure sql server?

Tags: azure-sql-database, dacpac

We have a sql deploy package, aka `dacpac` with an altered definition of a sql view.

Is there any reason why the deploy process might fail to `alter` the existing view? The sql deploy step of the deployment pipeline ran without error as usual so no clues there.

It's only failing to work in our azure pipeline deployment, it works okay running against a local database. It's the first time we've encountered this issue even though we've been using the dacpac for well over a year.

If anyone knows how dacpacs decide what alter statements to issue that would be useful.

---

Sorry this is a bit vague but we're clutching at straws. We'd ditch the awful dacpac system if we could, but that'll take a bit longer. Obvious answers such as "is it pointing at the right database" welcome as any wild guesses could get us there.

Comment: what changes are there in view definition ? is it just a case change ?

Comment: Several new fields added, and some rearranged, certainly something I'd expect it to notice.

Comment: try to generate difference report and see if view is included: refer to SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534330/ssdt-track-database-changes-from-dacpac-deployment

Comment: Typically having just asked, yet another attempt at creating a release *from the same build* and deploying it finally worked. It just adds evidence to my opinion that dacpacs are to be avoided due to their non-deterministic deployments. I appreciate the input and ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the view should be altered as part of the DACPAC publish. If it is not happening, it could be because view is mentioned as excluded object.

```
/p: ExcludeObjectType=(STRING) Views
/p: ExcludeObjectTypes=(STRING) Views;Triggers
```

[Sql Package Publish options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep creating new releases from the same build until one of them deploys correctly.

This should not be the answer because the dacpac is unchanged, but it's what ended up working.

I can only guess this is because the dacpac figures out what changes to make at deploy time by inspecting the database and is therefore fundamentally non-deterministic. Just what you don't want for a system for changing your production database schema.